# Mule Studio custom component library - icon and properties?

Tags: mule

I'm planning to implement a library of components for use with Mule Studio (i.e. for Mule 3.x) that supports a special business area.

If you start a fresh Mule Studio installation there is a set of bundled Endpoints, Components etc, like e.g. Java, Logger, SOAP etc, all with their own icon and set of properties that you can drag-and-drop on a Mule flow.

My question is, for the sake of usability, is there any way that I can seamlessly integrate my own components into Mule Studio's palette of components, endpoints etc? I.e. basically I would like to have icons and properties just as the built in ones.

I know that I can use e.g. the Java component and configure each component similar to like:

```
<component doc:name="Test">
    <singleton-object class="test.MyComponent">
        <property key="size" value="10"/>
    </singleton-object>
</component>
```

or use Spring components etc. but that's not really what I want. I'm more interested in getting the visualization of the flow to include my custom symbols and let the user work with them.

Regards, Ola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Mulesoft Devkit in order to  create your components. Mule Devkit is a great tool developed by Mulesoft that allows you to create new components for your app very easily. The new release of devkit generates an update site for your connector/module/component  so it can be easily integrated into studio.

Check out this page, follow the steps and you will have your components in the studio palette!. It will take you just 5 minutes!

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/DEVKIT/Your+First+Cloud+Connector

Regards,

Fernando